# Excel array formula with criteria

Tags: excel-formula

I want to multiply elements in an array (table) based on certain criteria.
In the example below I want to multiply all values where the year is `2019`.

```
| Year | Value |
|------|-------|
| 2017 | 0.5   |
| 2017 | 0.1   |
| 2018 | 0.1   |
| 2018 | 0.05  |
| 2019 | 0.1   |
| 2019 | 0.1   |
```

I have tried something like `{=IF(Table1[Year]=2019,PRODUCT(Table1[Value]))}` (entered using array formula) but it returns `FALSE`. Other attempts it returned `0` as it did not filter out the cells correctly.

The answer I want to get is `0.01`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this array formula :

```
=PRODUCT(IF(Table1[Year]=2019,(Table1[Value])))
```